# Why is doesn't $\frac{49^t}{2041}$ = $\frac{(7^t)^2}{2041}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lets assume t = 3

$\frac{49^3}{2041}$ = 57.64

$\frac{(7^3)^2}{2041}$ = 57.64

But according to Khan Academy they're not the same... How is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide the link?

Comment: They are equal. Recall: $(a^b)^c = a^{bc} = (a^c)^b$ and that $49=7^2$.

Comment: The Khan academy says they're not the same? Well, I'll be....perhaps those guys know something secret we still don't...

Comment: Forth answer is right, third answer is wrong, i.imgur.com/HJ5TQoe.jpg @user88595

Comment: @user11406 $$7^{t^2} \neq (7^t)^2$$ except for some special values of $t$.

Comment: Could you explain why that would be the case?

Comment: Because exponents are evaluated from top down. You are doing $t^2$ before you do anything else on the left side.

Comment: $\;t^2\neq 2t\;$ , in general, and by exponents laws $\;\left(7^t\right)^2= 7^{2t}\neq7^{t^2}\;$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:** Nevermind, as @DanielFischer points out, the two sides of the equality were misreported. The quantities are indeed not the same.

---

They are indeed the same expressions for all values of $t$. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2849%5Et%29+%2F+2041+%3D%3D+%28%287%5Et%29%5E2%29+%2F+2041).

Perhaps the Khan Academy software has some sort of [numerical error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_error). Numerical error is when computers operating with finite precision (i.e. a fixed number of digits of accuracy) show erroneous results when representing real number values (potentially infinite precision).

Comment: Why would you use W|A to "check" such a thing?

Comment: Forth is right, third is wrong, http://i.imgur.com/HJ5TQoe.jpg

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I don't need W|A to check it for myself; showing OP that such a tool exists may mean we won't get this sort of question from him/her in the future.

Answer (score 2):

On the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmxv7.jpg) you say fourth is right but third is wrong. That's correct

You are confused with where the square is :
$$7^{t^2} \ne (7^t)^2$$
For most values of $t$.
In the first case you first calculate $t^2$ and then put $7$ to that power. In the second, you put $7$ to the power $t$ and then square it.

Check with $t = 3$ that you indeed have two different things.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the confusion lies in the fact that $7^{t^2}$ is not meant as $(7^t)^2$. Rather think of it as $7^{(t^2)}$ where $t^2$ is a whole entity. We can check this for some values:

Suppose $t=1$ then $7^{(t^2)} = 7^{(1^2)} = 7^1 = 7$ however $(7^t)^2 = (7^1)^2 = 7^2 = 49$.

Suppose $t = 3$ then $7^{(t^2)} = 7^{(3^2)} = 7^9$; however $(7^t)^2 = (7^3)^2 = 7^{3\times 2} = 7^6$.

We can see from these examples that these notations mean very different things. (Note that these two expressions are the same if $t=0$ or $t=2$ though..)

Answer (score 2):

In the question you link to, the numerator of the fourth answer is $7^{t^2}$, which is not the same as $(7^t)^2$  The usual grouping is $7^{t^2}=7^{(t^2)}\neq (7^t)^2=49^t$